# PHP SOAP passing ComplexType parameter

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am trying to call SOAP service from my web app. I create a soap client without problem but I am having problem calling SOAP method GetCustomer. I get followinf SOAP error

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'any' property.
```

I think the problem is in supplied parameters. The parameters are of type `ComplexType` and I am not sure if I pass it right from PHP. Here is WSDL from GetCustomer method:

```
<s:element name="GetCustomer">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="user" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="xmlParams">
                <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

I have found [this article](http://leifmadsen.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/consuming-soap-complextype-webservice-with-php/) that addresses this issue, when I applied this to my code I get the above error. Here is my PHP code:

```
$params = new StdClass();
$params->user = '****';
$params->password = '****';
$params->xmlParams = new StdClass();

$soap_options = array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions'  => 1 );
$wsdl = "https://web-icdev.saop.si/iCenter_WS/SAOPWS_Customer.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soap_options);

try {
    $result = $client->GetCustomer($params);
    var_dump($result);
} 
catch (SOAPFault $f) {
    echo $f->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create 3 files:

1.GetCustomer.class.php

```
<?php 
class GetCustomer{ 
var $user; 
var $password;
var $xmlParams;
}
```

2.xmlParams.class.php

```
<?php 
class xmlParams{ 
}
```

2.ServiceConsumer.php

```
 <?php
 include_once 'GetCustomer.class.php';
 include_once 'xmlParams.class.php';

 $objGetCust = new GetCustomer();
 $objGetCust->user = '****';
 $objGetCust->password = '****';
 $objGetCust->xmlParams = new xmlParams();

 $soap_options = array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions'  => 1 );
 $wsdl = "https://web-icdev.saop.si/iCenter_WS/SAOPWS_Customer.asmx?WSDL";
 $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soap_options);

 try {
    $result = $client->GetCustomer($params);
    var_dump($result);
 }catch (SOAPFault $f) {
        echo $f->getMessage();
 }
```

This is the way that I work with those kind of webservices, also you can put GetCustomer and xmlParams Classes in the file **ServiceConsumer.php** or maybe both in the same file called.

But I prefer to use all in diferent files.

Best Regards.

Comment: Also you can create an array with the same estructure `$params = ['user' => '****', 'password' => '****', 'xmlParams' => []]` haven't tested this explicit example, but worked for me on something similar.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$params = new StdClass();

$params->user = '****';

$params->password = '****';

$foo = new StdClass();

$foo->any = $yourXML;

$param->xmlParams = $foo;

$soap_options = array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions'  => 1 );

$wsdl = "https://web-icdev.saop.si/iCenter_WS/SAOPWS_Customer.asmx?WSDL";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soap_options);

try {
    $result = $client->GetCustomer($params);
    var_dump($result);
} 
catch (SOAPFault $f) {
    echo $f->getMessage();
}
```